# Redirecting all addresses, except those on a port number

Tags: apache, redirect

I've been using such redirection in apache

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

And it wsa fine till now. I need a test site to be set up on a 8080 port number. How to exclude 8080 from that redirection. So www.example.com:8080 would not redirect to www.example.com

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
```

from:
[Administration Over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL#Rewrite_for_sites_running_on_port_443_or_port_80)